# Highlight startDate in CalendarDateInterval Control

Tags: javascript, calendar, sapui5

i've set the start Date in the CalendarDateInterval Control with

```
self.getView().byId("calendar").setStartDate(DeliveryDate); //DeliveryDate = 25. October
```

now it looks like this:

[image]

That's ok because now it's in my focus. But i want to highlight the start date like this

[image]

It is only highlighted with a click. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
var cal = this.byId("calendar")
cal.focusDate(DeliveryDate); 
cal.insertSelectedDate(new DateTypeRange({ startDate : DeliveryDate }));
```

Answer (score 1):

for Highlight day of current Month in sapui5 calendar.

e.g. below code will highlight the 12th day of that month.

```
var Cal = this.byId("DatePicker1");

Cal.addSpecialDate(new sap.ui.unified.DateTypeRange({
    startDate: new Date(oRefDate.setDate(12)),
    type: "Type11",
   color: "#009A9B"
 }));

For specific date highlight:-
var myDate = new Date("2020-11-20");

Cal.addSpecialDate(new sap.ui.unified.DateTypeRange({
    startDate: myDate,
    type: "Type11",
    color: "#009A9B"
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.unified.Calendar.html#insertSelectedDate ?

```
this.getView().byId("calendar").insertSelectedDate(DeliveryDate);
```

Comment: Error: ... is not valid for aggregation "selectedDates" of Element sap.ui.unified.CalendarDateInterval#__xmlview2--....

Comment: This cannot work. Method insertSelectedDate expects a parameter of type sap.ui.unified.DateRange. Checkout this example: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.unified.sample.CalendarDateIntervalBasic/preview